Proof of the fact that every 4-dimensional triangulation is PL
I've been trying to wrap my head around the fact that every triangulation of a 4-manifold must be PL. I have found the following answer:
Equivalence of triangulations and piecewise-linear triangulations in dimension $d\leq 4$
However, I'm having serious trouble trying to understand how this proof works out, given that I can't find anything in the proof preventing it from showing that the double-suspension of a homology sphere is a PL triangulation, unless I'm missing something extremely obvious. I have a feeling that the issue hinges on the fact that $L_v$ has to be a manifold, but I'm not too sure on why this should hold in a 4-manifold triangulation.

Hint: Think about links of vertices in a 4-manifold triangulation. These links are some 3-dimensional manifolds. What are these?

Aren't they objects with the homology of a sphere? But why are they manifolds in this case?

For that, you should take a look at the links of the edges. But links of vertices are more than just homology spheres. If you take the cone over, say, Poincare homology sphere, will it be a topological manifold?

Isn't there a theorem (I think by cannon) stating that a homology manifold is a topological manifold if and only if the link of each vertex is simply-connected? Therefore $S\Sigma$ is not a manifold?

So what prevents me from reproducing the proof, e.g. for $S^2\Sigma$ is the fact that the tridimensionality of $L_v$ forces it to be a manifold?

The key difference is that a surface which is a homology $2$-sphere is homeomorphic to $S^2$, while there are 3-manifolds which are homology $3$-spheres and not homeomorphic to $S^3$. And you cannot argue that these homology spheres are simply-connected since removing an arc from a 5-dimensional manifold can change its fundamental group (while removing a point from a 4-dimensional manifold cannot). Strange but true.
